# What platforms does Resonance support?

Tags: unity-game-engine, xbox-one, resonance-audio, ps4

I've looked all over but I can't find a comprehensive list of what platforms Resonance supports.

Does it support PS4 or XBox One? Specifically for Unity.

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't support PS or XBox if your unity did.

Comment: @Bijan You don't know Google. Most of their projects targets mobile devices like iOS and Android only. When I say most I actually mean all. It would be surprising if it works for ps4 and xbox-one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Resonance Audio supports Windows, OSX, iOS, and Android. But they made it open source a few months ago, so Xbone or PS4 support might be achievable.